# Grey Box instead of Google Map after refreshing page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a Google Map with Markers on it.  Each of the markers has an info-box associated with it.  The information need to populate the info-box is fetched with an ajax call.  The problem is, after selecting one of the markers which makes an ajax call, if completed successfully, whenever you refresh/reload the page the Google Map is just a grey box.

```
var map, markers = [];
var initMap = function (latitude, longitude) {
    var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(latitude), parseFloat(longitude));
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        minZoom:2,
        center: coords,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        scaleControl: true
     }
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('search-map'), mapOptions)
};
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    maxWidth: 350,
    shadowStyle: 1,
    padding: 0,
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(57,57,57)',
    borderRadius: 4,
    arrowSize: 10,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#2c2c2c',
    arrowPosition: 30,
    arrowStyle: 2
});
var contentString = "stuff"
for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: markers[i][0],
        map: map,
        icon: markers[i][1]
    })
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            $.post($(ajaxURL, userIdObj, function(response) {
                infowindow.close();
                infowindow.setContent(contentString);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            })
        }
    })(marker, i));
}
```

Comment: You're passing `latitude` and `longitude` to your `initMap` method - something tells me that your AJAX call must be messing with however you are passing those parameters in. You map is then created with no center, and all you end up with is a grey box.

Comment: Thanks @Adam I'll look into that!

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, just a quick update. 
Working on this task I actually experienced two types of "grey boxes."
One where I could see the google logo at the bottom and one where I could not.  If you can see the google logo at the bottom, as stated above you have to resize. Something along these lines: `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');`
If you can't see anything in the grey box, it is most likely an issue with the function that you initialize the map with in particular the `center:new google.maps.LatLng(39.739318, -89.266507)`

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this too, but after drawing the map you need only resize it with something like

```
$('google-map').resize();
```

to make it visible.